# Is this an attempt to mess with the shop?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, security

when i check in backend, customers online, is see an ip address viewing the site with a url that is strange

The url structure is:

https://www.mydomain.com/nl/category/page.html

but i see someone using

/nl/catalog/product_compare and nl/catalog/category/view/id/6

i do not use the word catalog...

Is this something to worry about and if so, how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you set `URL Key` for your products as rewrites for the actual product link, it will still appear the magento way in the backend, i.e. nl/catalog/category/view/id/6.